# ArgumentOutOfRange when adding root level nodes into treeview

Tags: c#, asp.net, treeview

I get ArgumentOutOfRange exception when I try to add nodes into a treeview using the code below:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            if (Page.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
               NavigationTree.Nodes.Add(AuthUserNode);

            }
            else
            {
                NavigationTree.Nodes.Remove(AuthUserNode);
            }
         }
     }
```

However I am able to add nodes as a child node of some node

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            if (Page.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
               NavigationTree.Nodes[0].ChildNodes.Add(AuthUserNode);

            }
            else
            {
                NavigationTree.Nodes.Remove(AuthUserNode);
            }
         }
     }
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: don't know exactly but is only one root-node allowed?

Comment: no it's not - and the doc: http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/58hx3b2a.aspx gives no hint of a "OutOfRange" exception .. strange. Where does the AuthUserNode come from?

Comment: How do you know that there are any nodes to remove in the else statement?  Are you trying to remove nodes when there are none?

Comment: Does the code run if you insert a string instead of the node?

Comment: @Ben: I thought along the same lines first but the documentation says nothing about any exceptions on remove - I guess it just ignores the call if the treenode is not port of the collection (same as other instances of .Remove in the framework - only that normaly you will get a boolean answer)

Comment: AuthUserNode is a field of the page and removing it always works successful. It does not throw an exception if it is not in the tree.

Comment: @Ckoenig, yes but that could be just be incomplete documentation, i can't see how adding a noide to a treeview could throw an IndexOutOfRangeException but i am pretty sure accessing Node[1] when there is only one node will throw that exception.  I would not be surprised if removing a none existent node throws the same exception

Comment: @Ben: I don't think it is a good idea to discuss here but I tried the following code <pre><code>            var notThere = new TreeNode("not there");
            treeView1.Nodes.Remove(notThere); </code></pre> and it works without complain

Comment: @Kta: what kind of field (type) is this? If it is a TreeNode than do you "new" it up or do you get it from somewhere else - I ask because there is the hint that an exception will be thrown when the node belongs to another TreeView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I have found the error. It is thrown when the node is already present at that level. I wish the exception would be more explanatory though.